# https and wss ran in local ip address

Tags: javascript, python, apache, websocket, https

I do those instructions: https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/

I want to test a Secure Web Socket Connection on Lan NetWork.
I try to run the websocket server (python) in 192.168.1.24 which is the static lan ip address of my pc at port 8080.

When i try to fetch an html page with a javascript web socket connection in it, i saw this:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://192.168.1.24:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Is there any way to have https (i need it for js getUserMedia function) and wss protocol in a lan ip address?

Thanks in advance,

Chris Pappas

Answer (score 0):

The websocket connected using the IP, not covered by the certificate, so changing the socket address from `wss://192.168.1.24:8080/` to `wss://somehost:8080/` (edit file named '`hosts`' in your OS, if need)